# Dropdown select option pagination in ng-table

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, pagination, ngtable

I need to create a dynamic ng-table with pagination. But I want to create a drop down with select option a “Show 50, 100, All” with next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy change pagination template, like in [example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/2),
in your case you can combine [ngtable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) and [jseppi dropdown plugin](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns).
like here

#### pagination template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
        <ul class="pager ng-cloak">
          <li ng-repeat="page in pages"
                ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active, 'previous': page.type == 'prev', 'next': page.type == 'next'}"
                ng-show="page.type == 'prev' || page.type == 'next'" ng-switch="page.type">
            <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&laquo; Previous</a>
            <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Next &raquo;</a>
          </li>
            <li> 
            <div dropdown-select="ddSelectOptions"
                 dropdown-model="ddSelectSelected"
                 dropdown-item-label="text"
                 dropdown-onchange="params.count(selected.value)" 
                 >

            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
```

#### controller

```
...
$scope.ddSelectOptions=[{
            text: '10',
            value: 10
        },{
            text: '20',
            value: 20
        },{
            text: '30',
            value: 30
        },
        {
            text: '100',
            value: 100
        },

        ];

        $scope.ddSelectSelected={
            text: '10',
            value: 10
        };

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
...
```

Working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tu4zZPgXl9laFBoCkWUo?p=preview).

#### Update 5/8/2016

CDN links were broken so here working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0yNbraQEQGkhGzDWxd0J)

please note that answer was for version `0.3.0` , latest version with some little breaking [changes](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) should be `1.0.0`

Comment: i have checked your plunk but code is not working there. no data is showing.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar please check updated answer, cdn links were broken, now it's fixed